# Can a discrete sinusoidal signal represent only limited number of frequencies?

Tags: discrete-signals

If $\omega$ is the frequency of a continuous time sinusoidal signal, $-\infty < \omega < \infty $.

But when it comes to discrete time sinusoidal signals, the range becomes limited : $-\pi \le \omega_{discrete} \le \pi $.

Does that mean discrete sinusoidal signals cannot represent all frequencies possible ? What is the true picture here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is important to realize that in the discrete-time case, $\omega$ is normalized by the sampling frequency $f_s$:

$$\omega=2\pi f/f_s$$

The inequality in your question is basically the [sampling theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem), which says that a discrete-time signal can only represent frequencies lower than half the sampling frequency. All higher frequencies will be folded back into the frequency band $[0,f_s/2]$ (this is called [aliasing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing)). If you need higher frequencies then you need to increase the sampling rate.

Comment: Essentially, once we select a sampling rate, it constrains the representable frequency range. Correct ?

Comment: @curryage: Right.